# How to dispaly menu at bottom similar to ios game center "add photo" feature

Tags: ios

In iphone game center app, there is a feature "add photo". When I tap on the "add photo", it displays a menu at the bottom.

**is there an ios api to do the same??**

I have seen the same behavior across many apps (ios/third-party).

Comment: I just checked it out myself and that "menu" is simply an Action Sheet saying "Choose Photo," "Take Photo," and "Cancel"... No fancy business required...

Comment: oh...thanks...let me try

Comment: In iOS 8 the UIActionSheet was replaced by UIAlertController.

Comment: @Fogmeister Of type Action Sheet.

Comment: @LyndseyScott yup. I still find it a bit odd that they deprecated a load of stuff and replaced it with almost identical stuff. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for iOS 8 you should not be using UIActionSheet.

For iOS 8 they replaced it with UIAlertController. This is what you are seeing in the Game Center app.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [`UIActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html). Here's a tutorial on how to implement it: [LINK](http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: As Fogmeister noted in his answer, UIActionSheet has been deprecated.